# in matlab Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket for definite integral

Tags: matlab

I'm writing a program that can solve the equation of motion for an inverted pendulum. However, on the line "F=int ... ", I get an error saying "unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket". However, I checked it many times and it seems that the bracket/parenthesis are balanced. I'm guessing the error is coming from the part "s,tn-(n/2),tn+(n/2)", but I'm not sure why

```
function [ theta ] = Untitled( theta_o,omega_o )

nt=5001; %since (50-0)/.01 = 5000
dt = .01; % =H
H=.01;

theta_n = ones(nt,1);
theta_n(1)=0; %theta_o

omega_n = ones(1,nt);
omega_n(1)=-0.4; %omega_o

epsilon=10^(-6);
eta = epsilon*10;

t_o=0;

for n=1:4999
    tn=t_o+n*dt;
    F=int((422.11/eta)*exp[[5*(4*((eta*t-s-tn)^2)/eta^2)-1]^(-1)]*omega, s,tn-(n/2),tn+(n/2))
    theta_n(n+1) = theta_n(n) + h*F;
end

end
```

EDIT: I converted the [] into (), and now the error "Undefined function or variable 't'."

Comment: Those square brackets should be [parenthesis](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/specialcharacters.html).

Comment: I converted the [] into (), and now get the error "Undefined function or variable 't'."

Answer (score 1):

As @Molly pointed out in her comment the correct line should be:

```
F=int((422.11/eta)*exp((5*(4*((eta*t-s-tn)^2)/eta^2)-1)^(-1))*omega, s,tn-(n/2),tn+(n/2))
```

You cannot use square brackets `[` and `]` in Matlab like you would use them when writing maths on paper. Use round brackets `(` and `)` for all brackets in Matlab.

Square brackets are used to denote matrices in Matlab.

EDIT: That error is because in you code you have `eta*t` but you have not told MATLAB what `t` is. My guess is that it should be either `tn` or `dt`, or you need to define it as something:

```
t = %the correct value for t
```

But, I am not familiar with the problem you are trying to solve, so I suggest checking that you copied down the formula correctly.

Comment: I converted the [] into (), and now get the error "Undefined function or variable 't'."

Comment: @MK did setting the value for t fix your problem?